# Text-to-column data split in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hi and thanks in advance I am new to excel vba and macro and need help on some little problem

I have a excel file that contain recordset that imported form ms access that contain product Name. I need to separate the product name into multiple column by clicking button. For some product Name the text may have different length and also i want to separate if-only the name consist 3A. The example i want to do is as shown below:

```
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+
|Name         | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+
|3A071908-253 |  3A  |  07  |  19  |  08  | 253  |
|3A011910R-220|  3A  |  01  |  19  |  10  | 220  |
|3A041912-123R|  3A  |  04  |  19  |  12  | 123  |
|WW071908-123 |      |      |      |      |      |
|13A131902-010|  3A  |  13  |  19  |  02  | 010  |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I have tried macro that using text to column wizard function with fixed width to get this done but the data does not appear as I want.

If there any formula or Codes to get this done.

Comment: Is the one infront of 3A a typo here `13A131902-010`? Or does this mean split the data whenever 3A is found and ignore everything infront of 3A? Please clarify.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ No it is not typo, Just ignore everything infront of 3A

Comment: Also please explain how this data is generated `3A041912-123R|  3A  |  04  |  12  |  08  | 123  ` why is it `04 | 12 | 08` and not `04 | 19 | 12`? Please be more precise.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ That is typo sorry for that. The data was generated to ms-access by using production machine software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following formulas in `Col1` to `Col5`:

- `=IF(ISERROR(FIND("3A",A:A)),"","3A")`
- `=IF($B:$B<>"",MID($A:$A,FIND("3A",$A:$A)+2,2),"")`
- `=IF($B:$B<>"",MID($A:$A,FIND("3A",$A:$A)+4,2),"")`
- `=IF($B:$B<>"",MID($A:$A,FIND("3A",$A:$A)+6,2),"")`
- `=IF($B:$B<>"",MID($A:$A,FIND("-",$A:$A)+1,3),"")`

[image]

Note that using  `FIND` is case sensitive that means `3a` will not be detected. If you want it case in-sensitive so it detects both `3a` and `3A` then change `FIND` to `SEARCH`.

Also note that all the extracted "numbers" in `Col2` to `Col5` are actually text. That means you are not able to calculate with them. If you need to convert them into real numbers to calculate use `VALUE()` like `=IF($B:$B<>"",VALUE(MID($A:$A,FIND("-",$A:$A)+1,3)),"")` for `Col5`.

Comment: This works as much as I want, Thanks for the incredible help

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your problem, these formulas should provide the functionality you're looking for. Starting in the first row of your data (presumed to be row 1 in the examples), from left to right:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("3A",$A1)),MID($A1,SEARCH("3A",$A1),2),"")
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("3A",$A1)),MID($A1,SEARCH("3A",$A1)+2,2),"")
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("3A",$A1)),MID($A1,SEARCH("3A",$A1)+4,2),"")
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("3A",$A1)),MID($A1,SEARCH("3A",$A1)+6,2),"")
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("3A",$A1)),MID($A1,SEARCH("3A",$A1)+9,3),"")
```

You could do this in a more sophisticated way using VBA but I think this simple approach will suffice for your use case.

Comment: This one works too, I will try to use it as an alternative to see which one is suits more to what I want to achieve